QueryHandler load balancing when scaling app
When I'm scaling my application that handles queries I'd expect the multiple instances to get a somewhat load balanced amount of request. But all queries end up on one instance:

There are multiple external services firing these queries using a QueryGateway. What I'm want is async request/reply services that are able to distribute load when many requests are send. Is this not the usecase for QueryGateways?
Given this QueryHandler in a spring boot application:
@Component
public class CalculateProfanityScoreQueryHandler {

  @QueryHandler
  public CompletableFuture<ProfanityScore> handle(CalculateProfanityScoreQuery query) {
    int score = rateComment();
    ProfanityScore profanityScore = new ProfanityScore(score);
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(profanityScore);
  }
}

And external services connected to the same Axon Server instance making requests like this:
 @Override
  public ProfanityEvaluation calculateScore(String comment) {
    var profanityScore =
        queryGateway
            .query(
                new CalculateProfanityScoreQuery(comment),
                ResponseTypes.instanceOf(ProfanityScore.class))
            .get();

    // rest of logic
  }

Overview in Axon dashboard for given service scaled to 6 instances:


Are you sure all instances of the application have subscribed the same query? You can see the subscribed queries of each app by clicking on the app in the overview screen.

I believe so, I've updated the question with a screenshot of the overview with just these scaled up services. I've had zero additional config in the application for axon.

Its working as expected with axonserver 2024.0 and 2023.1.2-dev (i'm using SE versions). Its broken in all 2023.2.x versions.

It's working as expected with axonserver 2024.0 and 2023.1.2-dev (i'm using SE versions). It's broken in all 2023.2.x versions. It will only use the first query handler instance (sorted alphabetically by Instance Name).
